# invoking method that takes string array as parameter results in IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, reflection

I'm using runtime reflection to load a class which contains the following two methods:

```
public static void foo(int[] args)
{
    System.out.print("foo invoked: ");
    for(int arg : args)
        System.out.print(arg + " ");
    
    System.out.println();
}

public static void bar(String[] args)
{
    System.out.print("bar invoked: ");
    for(String arg : args)
        System.out.print(arg + " ");
    
    System.out.println();
}
```

*(identical methods except one takes an int array and the other takes a string array)*

I then attempt to invoke the two methods like so:

```
    int[] intArr = {1,2,3};
    clazz.getMethod("foo", int[].class).invoke(null, intArr);

    String[] strArr = {"1","2","3"};
    clazz.getMethod("bar", String[].class).invoke(null, strArr); //Exception
```

*(here 'clazz' is the class the two methods reside in, which i have loaded at runtime)*

The first invocation causes no exceptions and outputs the expected output, but the second invocation throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at ReflectionTests.main(ReflectionTests.java:63)
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Observe that `invoke` has this signature:

```
public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)
```

`args` is a variable-arity parameter to allow you to pass each parameter of the invoked method as a parameter of `invoke`, e.g.

```
someStaticMethod.invoke(null, param1, param2, param3);
```

would call:

```
someStaticMethod(param1, param2, param3);
```

On the other hand, the type of `args` is really just `Object[]`, and there exists a conversion from `String[]` to `Object[]`, since arrays are covariant.

So when you pass your `String[]` of `strArr` to `invoke`, one of two things could happen:

- `strArr` is converted to an `Object[]`, and each `String` is treated as a parameter to the method to be invoked.
- the whole `strArr` is treated as one of the parameter of the method to be invoked, just like a non-array type would.

The compiler just so happens to prefer the first one (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2). Note how variable-arity invocation has the lowest priority), so you are actually passing the parameters `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"` to the method, rather than *one* single `String[]`.

On the other hand, `int[]` can't be converted to `Object[]` directly, because `int` is primitive, so the compiler can only choose the second option above.

One way to force the second option is to cast to `Object`:

```
clazz.getMethod("bar", String[].class).invoke(null, (Object)strArr);
```

Another way is to create another `Object[]` wrapping the `String[]`:

```
clazz.getMethod("bar", String[].class).invoke(null, new Object [] { strArr });
```

Comment: In case anyone wonders why the compiler prefers the first behavior, it’s because `invoke(null, strArr)` was a valid invocation before *varargs* were introduced and hence, it’s behavior was not allowed to change. In contrast, any argument that is not assignable to `Object[]` was not valid before *varargs*, therefore there is no compatibility problem with now stuffing an `int[]` argument into an array behind the scenes, to treat it as a single arguments to the reflected method.

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass as first parameter of the invoke() method the initialized object that is going to execute that method.

Foo foo = new Foo();
Method method = clazz.getMethod("method");

method.invoke(foo, params[ ]);

The invoke() needs the object what is going to execute the method.

Comment: I dont believe you have to do this when the method is static. This is also indicated by the fact that the first method: 'foo' runs with no exceptions. It seems the problem has to do with passing a string array through this 'invoke' method.

Comment: As you have said, you do not believe it!